dynamic menu with ABP permission angular ui
Hi im building an angular application using ABP framework but all my components are libraries not from ABP and i want to render the menu based on the permissions that the user have
can i use abp routes service in order to do that ?
here is my menu build :
 menu: any[] = [
    {
      title: 'Sidebar::Menu:Main',
      children: [
        {
          title: 'Sidebar::Menu:Home',
          icon: 'flaticon-home',
          url: '/home',
        },
        {
          title: 'Sidebar::Menu:SaaS',
          icon: 'flaticon-people',
          permission: 'Saas.Tenants',
          children: [
            {
              title: 'Sidebar::Menu:Tenants',
              url: '/saas/tenants',
              permission: 'Saas.Tenants',
            },
            {
              title: 'Sidebar::Menu:Editions',
              url: '/saas/editions',
              permission: 'Saas.Editions',
            },
          ],
        },
        {
          title: 'Sidebar::Menu:Administration',
          icon: 'flaticon-setting',
          permission: 'AbpIdentity.ClaimTypes',
          children: [
            {
              title: 'Sidebar::Menu:IdentityManagement',
              permission: 'AbpIdentity.ClaimTypes',
              children: [
                {
                  title: 'Sidebar::Menu:OrganizationUnits',
                  url: '/identity/organization-units',
                  permission: 'AbpIdentity.OrganizationUnits',
                },
                {
                  title: 'Sidebar::Menu:Roles',
                  url: '/identity/roles',
                  permission: 'AbpIdentity.Roles',
                },
                {
                  title: 'Sidebar::Menu:Users',
                  url: '/identity/users',
                  permission: 'AbpIdentity.Users',
                },
                {
                  title: 'Sidebar::Menu:ClaimsTypes',
                  url: '/identity/claims-types',
                  permission: 'AbpIdentity.ClaimTypes',
                },
                {
                  title: 'Sidebar::Menu:SecurityLogs',
                  url: '/identity/security-logs',
                  permission: 'AbpIdentity.SecurityLogs',
                },
              ],
            },
            {
              title: 'Sidebar::Menu:OpenID',
              url: '/open-id',
              permission: 'OpenIddictPro.Application',
              children: [
                {
                  title: 'Sidebar::Menu:Applications',
                  url: 'applications',
                  permission: 'OpenIddictPro.Application',
                },
                {
                  title: 'Sidebar::Menu:Scopes',
                  url: 'scopes',
                  permission: 'OpenIddictPro.Scope',
                },
              ],
            },
            {
              title: 'Sidebar::Menu:LanguageManagement',
              url: '/language-management',
              permission: 'LanguageManagement.Languages',
              children: [
                {
                  title: 'Sidebar::Menu:Languages',
                  url: 'languages',
                  permission: 'LanguageManagement.Languages',
                },
                {
                  title: 'Sidebar::Menu:LanguageTexts',
                  url: 'language-texts',
                  permission: 'LanguageManagement.LanguageTexts',
                },
              ],
            },
            {
              title: 'Sidebar::Menu:TextTemplate',
              url: '/text-template',
              permission: 'TextTemplateManagement.TextTemplates',
            },
            {
              title: 'Sidebar::Menu:AuditLogs',
              url: '/audit-logs',
              permission: 'AuditLogging.AuditLogs',
            },
            {
              title: 'Sidebar::Menu:Settings',
              url: '/settings',
              permission: 'SettingManagement.Emailing',
              children: [
                {
                  title: 'Sidebar::Menu:Account',
                  url: 'account',
                  permission: 'AbpAccount.SettingManagement',
                },
                {
                  title: 'Sidebar::Menu:Emailing',
                  url: 'emailing',
                  permission: 'AbpAccount.Emailing',
                },
                {
                  title: 'Sidebar::Menu:FeatureManagement',
                  url: 'feature-management',
                  permission: 'FeatureManagement.ManageHostFeatures',
                },
                {
                  title: 'Sidebar::Menu:IdentityManagement',
                  url: 'identity-management',
                  permission: 'AbpIdentity.SettingManagement',
                },
                {
                  title: 'Sidebar::Menu:TimeZone',
                  url: 'time-zone',
                  permission: 'SettingManagement.TimeZone',
                },
              ],
            },
          ],
        },
      ],
    },
  ];

  constructor(
    private baseLayoutService: BaseLayoutService,
    private permissionService: PermissionsService,
    private routesService: RoutesService
  ) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.menu = this.filterMenu(this.menu);
  }

  filterMenu(menu: any[]): any[] {
    return menu
      .filter(
        (item) =>
          !item.permission ||
          this.permissionService.hasPermission(item.permission)
      )
      .map((item) => ({
        ...item,
        children: item.children ? this.filterMenu(item.children) : [],
      }));
  }

the approach im using is working fine but i want to make use of ABP services as much as possible, and also want the best practice and see if there is an ability to build it using
ABP routes service
